# FeatureTools: How to use featuretools where the relationship between datasets is many-to-many?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, featuretools

I have two dataframes A and B. A has an id `user_id` that is the unique id of the user and each row in this dataframe represents whether or not the user made a purchase. This has a timestamp for each instance of `userid` appearing in it. each `user_id` can make multiple purchases of different objects at different times. I have another table that has user_id associated with its history of window shopping along with a timestamp of this instance of window shopping and also contains the specifics of the item that the user_id was window shopping. As you can see there are multiple instances of `user_id` in this as well

featuretools [documentation](https://docs.featuretools.com/loading_data/using_entitysets.html) says

> Note that each ft.Relationship must denote a one-to-many relationship rather than a relationship which is one-to-one or many-to-many.

Comment: could you make a users entity that both of the purchase entity and the window shopping entity point to?

Comment: I can. But that would mean one feature vector created for each user_id. But the feature vector for one user_id has to be different based upon timestamp. When he purchased something in april, feature vector generation should consider window shopping till april and when he purchased something in december the feature vector generation should consider window shopping till december

Comment: @MaxKanter - any suggestions? do you want me to explain my situation better?

Comment: yes, any further details would be helpful. also, look at https://docs.featuretools.com/automated_feature_engineering/handling_time.html. using the cutoff_time parameter with a dataframe of user ids and time might be helpful